# JavaScript : When exactly the function assigned to the onload event executes?

Tags: javascript, events, callback, append, onload

```
function loadScript(src, callback) {
  let script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = src;

  script.onload = () => callback(script);

  document.head.append(script);
}

loadScript('/my/script.js', function() {
  ...
  ...
});
```

Here the callback function is executed when the onload event is triggered. But when onload event will be triggered? When appending the script does onload event is called? Because I see the execution of my callback function happens as soon as loadScript is called.

Comment: " Because I see the execution of my callback function happens as soon as loadScript is called." Okay, when did you expect it to be called?>

Comment: Well, how the DOM works was my question. We are appending the script dynamically. The script can be easily stored somewhere.for later use. But as soon as we append, the script will be loaded (onload will be called) and completely available in DOM was my question?

Answer (score 2):

It's executed after the script source is copied from the `script.src` URL into the DOM and the code in the script is executed.

Put some `console.log()` statements in `script.js` and the callback function and you should see the order that everything occurs.

Comment: Thank you Barmar